# how to answer questions in cmd using shelljs

Tags: node.js, cmd, shelljs

I'm putting together a script to create certificates for my devices, I thought I'd use shelljs to run these commands. I created a basic command for certificate generation, but the script stops running when cmd has a question, as in the example:

```
const shell = require('shelljs')
shell.exec("openssl genrsa -out deviceCert.key 2048")
shell.exec("openssl req -new -key deviceCert.key -out deviceCert.csr")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr27v.png)

I would like to know if there is any command that I can use to answer these cmd questions by shelljs itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
shell.exec("echo -ne 'AU' | openssl req -new -key deviceCert.key -out deviceCert.csr")
```

Comment: thanks, does this code work even if it is several questions in sequence?